# Windows app certification issue in UWP (Universal windows platform)

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-10-universal, windows-store

I have a winJS project that uses windows runtime component, for this I have enabled WinRT Access to **all**.

My app works fine on public network.

My client uses some type of private network and my app did not have permission for private network access.

For fixing this I enabled **Private Networks (Client & Server)** in Capabilities in package.appxmanifest file.

Now the app works fine in private networks too.

But then I had to put this app to windows store and when I carry out the windows certification kit test it **fails** with the following error:

> FAILED App manifest Error Found: The app manifest test detected the
>   following errors: The Application cannot include an
>   ApplicationContentUriRule with 'all' or 'allowForWebOnly'
>   WindowsRuntimeAccess while any of the following capabilities are
>   enabled: enterpriseAuthentication, sharedUserCertificates,
>   musicLibrary, picturesLibrary, videosLibrary, removableStorage,
>   documentLibrary, internetClientServer, privateNetworkClientServer.

Can anyone provide me some workaround ?

Thanks!

Comment: It is blocked because it's a security concern -- you're saying that any content from anywhere on the internet can use your app's permissions to attack the corporate network. What is the motivation for allowing "all" access?

Comment: I am using 'All' because I have to access windows runtime APIs. I don't think I can access them without having 'All' enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my knowledge and research, if you define 'ApplicationContentUriRule' with runtime access of 'ALL', the app fails while validating to windows store. This is because Microsoft considers that kind of configuration as a security risk.

Please refer this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fd28bcd5-b3a8-4307-be93-29fc4c5aaacd/uwpwork-around-for-application-content-uri-rule-windows-runtime-access?forum=wpdevelop , I think this will help you as well.